# Miking an upright bass

Tags: audio-recording, microphone-positioning, instruments

I am recording a live jazz quartet on Friday consisting of drums, acoustic piano, upright bass and either electric guitar or a sax (this will be confirmed tomorrow and I have no problem with these). As I have never recorded upright bass, I am lacking on miking techniques.

I have been researching into the subject but most places seem to be talking about when the instrument is isolated, and as I will be recording it completely live, some of the placements may not be ideal. I have heard of suspending an sm57 in the bridge with rubber bands but I'm not sure of the best way to achieve this. I am mainly looking to get a good sound out of the upright bass while minimizing the bleed from the other instruments.

Also, it will be plucked, not bowed.

Thanks, Oli.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SM57 in the bridge can work.  A good quality capsule condenser (like a LAV) clipped to the bridge can also work well.  Sure, it isn't ideal, but I haven't seen anything better for loud live environments.

Comment: Thanks, any tips on achieving this with rubber bands? I don't want to look a fool struggling to suspend it haha

Comment: No, that I can't help on, the player I did a full size mic with (wasn't actually a 57, but a similar shaped condenser) had a bridge clip that could hold the mic and folded some paper around the mic further up to wedge it in to the sound hole.

Comment: Also, would an AT899 work?

Comment: I'd guess you probably want something more like an ATM35.  I would think that an omnidirectional pickup in the AT899 is probably non-ideal as it will pick up not only the bass, but also everything around the bass.

Comment: ok, thanks for the help. Just one more thing, will the single sm57 or condenser be sufficient to get a good sound or would you recommend another close mix?

Comment: I've gotten sound good enough for the live mix off of micing at the bridge towards the sound chamber.  It takes some careful EQing, but was usable.  Again, I'm not sure it was the most ideal way, but it produced usable results.

Comment: I guess it won't harm to close mic it as I don't have to use it if it doesn't sound great. Thanks again!

Comment: If you use a second microphone i'd definitely place it pointing it to the lower third of the fingerboard, to get the sounds of plucking and the string pushing against the board. This complements the sound from the bridge-microphone very well. For the bridge I had good experiences with shoeps cardioid condenser or dpa lavaliers.